# Can a 4051 Multiplexer accept +/- 12v bipolar power

Tags: power, audio, multiplexer, bipolar

I'm looking to use a CD4051B multiplexer as a digitally-controlled switcher for audio signals.

The audio is coming from the HP / BP output of a voltage-controlled filter in a synth. The signal output is about 3v peak-to-peak. The mux select will be controlled by 5v TTL logic.

I only have supply voltages of 5v, 12v and -12v in my synth.

I'm finding the datasheets for the 4051 rather vague - has anyone had any success powering these chips with +/-12v bipolar power? (the -12v supply going to Vee)

Comment: If you're not tied to 4051s, Vishay do a splendid range of devices that work at +/-12V.   http://www.vishay.com/analog-switches/gt-6-v/

Answer (score 2):

The CD4051 is specified at rail to rail voltages from 5v to 20v. This is not enough to power directly from +/- 12v, but it is not necessary to have balanced rails, so powering the device from +5v and -12v will meet the required voltage range, see figure 9 of the [TI data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf).

This will allow direct coupling of voltages swinging about ground, with no need to AC couple. It will also allow logic control to be done with 0-5v, without a level shifter from the logic (simple or not!)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8fqI8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get home from work tonight..

Comment: +1 that's better than my proposed solution; as the 405x have level converters integrated that allow using it for analog signals below digital GND.

Comment: @Curd yes, I thought so too, using it like it's meant to be used usually wins out over adding lots of extra components, and shifting the signal unnecessarily. I added a diagram to show the reduced number of components. Were you thinking of doing anything with your answer that reflected that?

Comment: @Neil_UK: No. I looked at the datatsheet in detail (concerning the internal level converter for digital signals to use it with analog signals below digital GND) only after I've seen your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have the audio signal centered at 6V and power the 4051 with GND and 12V (it works with voltage supply up to 15V) and use a simple level shifter from 5V TTL to 12V (either inverting as shown in the diagram below or non-inverting; whatever suits better) for the logic signals.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG1D2w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are C1 / R1 / R1 providing the audio signal bias to 6v? Also, why is R3 connected to select pin bus?

Comment: Yes, R1, R2, C1 are for 6V biasing. R3 is a pull up-resistor that provides a +12V H-level (required if the 4051 is operated with Vdd=+12V). (This is needed for all digital logic inputs but shown only for one line).